# JSONObject converting BigDecimal to string

Tags: java, org.json

So, I have a class which are having 2 BigDecimal type fields. Now whenever I do

```
JSONObject ob = JSONObject(myObjectWithBigDecimals);
```

I see that the `ob` has the 2 BigDecimal fields enclosed in quotes. But I want them to be in float format. This is messing up how the data is stored in my NoSql DB.

This is how my class with BigDecimal fields looks like.

```
@Data
public class MyClassWithBigDecimals {
    BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    public MyClassWithBigDecimals() {
        a = a.setScale(6, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).stripTrailingZeros();
        b = b.setScale(6, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).stripTrailingZeros();
    }
}
```

And this is what I see in `ob`:

```
"{"a":"0","b":"0"}"
```

I want it to be:

```
"{"a":0,"b":0}"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please show the definition of the class of `myObjectWithBigDecimals`.

Comment: @k314159 Edited in the class.

Comment: What do you mean by "this is what I see on ob"? How do you see it? Is it by calling .toString()?

Comment: @k314159 I mean while debugging.

Comment: I think what you're seeing is the debugger calling the `BigDecimal.toString()` method in order to display the BigDecimal value. If you call `JSONObject.toString()` you'll get the right results.

Comment: @k314159 Thats not the case.